Purely inseparable field extensions - proving $\alpha^{p^m} \in F$ implies $m_\alpha = x^{p^m}-a^{p^m}$
I'm reading Isaacs' "Algebra: A Graduate Course" and I don't really understand the proof for the implication (2) $\Rightarrow$ (3) in Theorem 19.10 (page 298):

Suppose $F\subseteq E $ is an algebraic extension with $\textrm{char}F=p$, $p \neq 0$. The following are then equivalent:

$E$ is purely inseparable over $F$.
For each element $\alpha \in E$, there exists $n\ge 0$ such that $\alpha^{p^n} \in F$.
Each element of $E$ has minimal polynomial over $F$ of the form $x^{p^n}-a$ for some integer $n \ge 0$ and some element $a \in F$.


My trouble is with (2) implies (3). Given (2), I understand that $\alpha$ is a root of $g(x)=x^{p^n}-\alpha^{p^n} \in F[x]$. But then the author claims that for any monic irreducible factor $f(x)$ of $g(x)$ in $F[x]$ is of the form $(x-\alpha)^r$, and in particular $f(\alpha)=0$ implies that $f$ is the minimal polynomial of $\alpha$ over $F$, that it is uniquely determined, and that $g$ is a power of $f$ hence $f$ is of degree $p^m$ for some $m \in \mathbb N$.
My questions are:

Isn't any factor $f$ of $g$ of the form $(x-\alpha)^r$? Why specify it's irreducible?
I don't really understand in which section of the proof we're refering to a general factor $f$ of $g$ and when we're referring to the factor which is the minimal polynomial.
How is the degree of the minimal polynomial of $\alpha$ over $F$ being a divisor of $p^n$ implied? Why can't the minimal polynomial be of degree $r$ which is not a power of $p$?


If $f$ is a monic irreducible factor of $g$, then it is the irreducible polynomial of $\alpha$ over $F$. Thus to prove (3), we must argue $f$ has the form $x^{p^n}-a$.


Yes, it is true that any (monic) factor of $g(x)$ has the form $(x - \alpha)^r$. But the statement is phrased (at least in your question) such that we only consider factors $f$ which are irreducible (in $F[x]$), which is important because...
From the above statement, one can see that there is a unique irreducible factor of $g$, because any other factor $(x - \alpha)^{r'}$ either divides or is divisible by $(x - \alpha)^r$ (in $F[x]$). So a general irreducible factor (which has been named $f$) is in fact the minimal polynomial.
The fact that $f(x) = (x - \alpha)^r$ is the only irreducible factor of $g(x)$ implies $g(x)$ must be a power of $f(x)$; in particular, $\deg(f) = r$ divides $\deg(g) = p^n$.


To expand on (2), suppose $f(x) = (x - \alpha)^r$ and $f'(x) = (x - \alpha)^{r'}$ are in $F[x]$, and WLOG assume $r \le r'$. Then $f'(x) = f(x)(x-\alpha)^{r'-r}$, which implies $(x-\alpha)^{r'-r} \in F[x]$. So if $f$ and $f'$ are both irreducible, $(x-\alpha)^{r'-r}$ must be a unit, so that $r = r'$.
So together with (1), $g$ has a unique irreducible factor, which we call $f$. Since $g(\alpha) = 0$, the minimal polynomial of $\alpha$ divides $g$, so it must be $f$.

Thank you! Can you elaborate on (2)? If any other factor either divides or is divisible by $(x-\alpha)^r$ in $F[x]$, how does that imply that $(x-\alpha)^r$ is the only irreducible factor of $g$, hence is the minimal polynomial?

@RatherAmusing I have edited my post with some additional clarification - hope it helps.

Here is a proof of (2) implies (3):
Let $f(x)=\text{irr}(\alpha,F)$, the irreducible polynomial of $\alpha\in E$ over $F$.
Assume $\alpha^{p^m} \in F$.
Then $g(x)\overset{\text{def}}{=}x^{p^m}-\alpha^{p^m}$ is in $F[x]$ and admits $\alpha$ as a root, which implies $f(x)| g(x)$.
Observe that $g(x)=(x-a)^{p^m}$. Therefore $f(x)=(x-\alpha)^r$ for some $r$, which you have already observed.
It is well-known that we can select some $n$ s.t. $f(x)=\psi(x^{p^n})$ and $\psi\in F[x]$ is separable.
Let $\Omega$ be an algebraic closure of $F$ containing $E$.
We claim $\psi$ has only one root in $\Omega$.
In fact, if $\psi(y_1)=\psi(y_2)=0$ with $y_1,y_2\in\Omega$ and $y_1\ne y_2$, and let $\eta_1,\eta_2\in\Omega$ be s.t. $\eta_1^{p^n}=y_1$, $\eta_2^{p^n}=y_2$, then $\eta_1\ne\eta_2$ (for otherwise $y_1=y_2$) and $f(\eta_1)=f(\eta_2)=0$. This contradicts the fact that $f$ has only one root in $\Omega$, i.e., $\alpha$. Thus we conclude $\psi$ has only one root in $\Omega$.
Now, $\psi$ only has one root in $\Omega$, therefore we must have $\psi(x)=(x-a)^l$ for some $l\in\mathbb Z_+$. But $\psi$ is separable and therefore $l=1$, i.e. $\psi(x)=x-a$. Recall $\psi\in F[x]$, which implies $a\in F$. Therefore $\psi(x)=x-a$ with $a\in F$. Finally $f(x)=\psi(x^{p^m})=x^{p^m}-a$ with some $a\in F$. $\square$
